# PL/SQl, oracle 9i, deleting duplicate rows using sql

Tags: plsql, oracle9i

we have a scenario here where we need to delete all the duplicate rows from a table based on timestamp. The table structure looks like this:

```
Item   Ref1   Ref2        Timestamp
1      A       test1      2/3/2012 10:00:00
1      A       test2      2/3/2012 11:00:00
1      A       test1      2/3/2012 12:00:00
2      A       prod1      2/3/2012 10:00:00
2      B       prod2      2/3/2012 11:00:00
2      A       prod2      2/3/2012 12:00:00
```

So we need to delete the duplicate rows from this table based on item and ref1. like here we should have only 1 row for item 1 and ref1 A with the latest timestamp. Same for item 2 we should have only 1 row for ref1 A with latest timestamp.

Any pointers will be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your desired end result is a table with these 3 rows

```
Item   Ref1   Ref2        Timestamp
1      A       test1      2/3/2012 12:00:00
2      B       prod2      2/3/2012 11:00:00
2      A       prod2      2/3/2012 12:00:00
```

Something like

```
DELETE FROM table_name a
 WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1
                 FROM table_name b
                WHERE a.item = b.item
                  AND a.ref1 = b.ref1
                  AND a.timestamp < b.timestamp );
```

should work assuming that there are no two rows with the same `Item` and `Ref1` that both have the same `Timestamp`.  If there can be multiple rows with the same `Item` and `Ref1` that both have the latest `Timestamp` and assuming that you don't care which one you keep

```
DELETE FROM table_name a
 WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1
                 FROM table_name b
                WHERE a.item = b.item
                  AND a.ref1 = b.ref1
                  AND a.timestamp <= b.timestamp 
                  AND a.rowid     <  b.rowid);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can query your records grouping by Item and Ref1 an then delete where Item and Ref are equals and Timestamp < max.

```
select Item
     , Ref1
     , max(Timestamp) tm
  from table
 group by Item, Ref1
```

With the results...

```
delete from table where Item = ? and Ref1 = ? and Timestamp < ?
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an Oracle 9 install at hand, so I cannot test this, but I believe that this may work:

1. Create a view which lists adds "indices" to your records:

   `SELECT ROW_NUMBER( ) OVER (PARTITION BY Item, Ref1 ORDER BY Timestamp DESC) ix, * FROM table`
2. Delete the records from the view where `ix` is higher than 1