# SQL Duplication

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates, invoice

Context, - have a big invoice database. I'm looking for duplicates. Current situation brings me to looking for duplication in invoice numbers. I'm using count(*) to look for duplicates and to show me the ones that are duplicates whilst ignoring the others.

Problem  - Count(*) isn't working, it does show the dummy duplicates I've put in as test data, but it still shows records that aren't duplicates.

Here's a part of the code so you can get the gist of it:

```
sql dbselect s2.apar_id, s2.ext_inv_ref as John3, s2.ext_inv_ref as INVNO, s2.cur_amount, ABS(s2.cur_amount) as ABSAMT, s2.trans_date, s2.period, s2.voucher_no, s2.voucher_type,s3.apar_name, s3.apar_gr_id

sql from asuhistr s2, asuheader s3

sql where ( s2.ext_inv_ref in
sql (select s2.ext_inv_ref
    sql from asuhistr s1
    sql and s1.apar_id = '######'
    sql group by s2.ext_inv_ref
    sql having (count(*)> 1))
```

Sadly it doesn't remove the non-duplicate invoice numbers.

### Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's full code:

```
sql dbselect s2.apar_id, s2.ext_inv_ref as John3, s2.ext_inv_ref as INVNO, s2.cur_amount, ABS(s2.cur_amount) as ABSAMT, s2.trans_date, s2.period, s2.voucher_no, s2.voucher_type,s3.apar_name, s3.apar_gr_id

sql from asuhistr s2, asuheader s3
sql where ( s2.ext_inv_ref in
sql (select s2.ext_inv_ref
    sql from asuhistr s1
    sql and s1.apar_id = '######'
    sql group by s2.ext_inv_ref
    sql having (count(*)> 1))
sql and s3.client = s2.client
sql and s3.apar_id = s2.apar_id
sql and s2.apar_id = '######'
sql order by s2.apar_id
query
```

The output this gives is:
Supplier ID, Supplier Name, Invoice Number, Amount, Date, etc.. (I'm only focusing on invoice number at the moment)

For example, running the above code it gives me:

```
Supplier ID     Supplier Name       Invoice Number
123456            Abcdefg              999999
568224            rtyuiop              445254
782387            asdasda              999999
734756            werqewq              215423
331231            hdfgsaf              515154
```

I want it to only display:

```
Supplier ID     Supplier Name       Invoice Number
123456            Abcdefg              999999
782387            asdasda              999999
```

Comment: Your code is invalid SQL, please post the **real** queries you are using. What is `sql dbselect` supposed to do?

Comment: It would help if you add sample data and expected results. It is not completely clear what "duplicate" means for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PL/SQl, oracle 9i, deleting duplicate rows using sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133277/pl-sql-oracle-9i-deleting-duplicate-rows-using-sql)

Comment: Just updated the question, please have a look @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Just updated the question, please have a look @Bulat

Comment: `sql dbselect` is still invalid SQL

Comment: it works, don't worry about that - maybe oracle? @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: A statement that starts with `sql dbselect` will most definitely not run in any Oracle client. Neither will Oracle allow `sql` as the start of each line in a query.

Comment: it's running though.... @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: what is in apar_id field?

Comment: it is the identification number for the supplier i.e. Supplier ID @Bulat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
s2.ext_inv_ref
```

With:

```
s1.ext_inv_ref
```

in your subquery:

```
... (select s1.ext_inv_ref
from asuhistr s1
    and s1.apar_id = '######'
group s1.ext_inv_ref
having (count(*)> 1) ..
```

Comment: doesn't make a difference - changed it and it gave me the same results... @Bulat

Comment: did you replace both places?

Comment: first I replaced inside the subquery, same results.
Then I replaced outside subquery as well, resulted in error

Comment: there are two instances in subquery where you use s2. Only use s1 in subquery.

Comment: I have s2 outside subquery and inside I have s2. I changed from s2 to s1 inside the query, but it gave me the same result.

Comment: well, you need to use s1 only in the subquery. if it still does not work, you need to update the question, as using s2 in subquery is definitely a mistake.

Comment: OMG! IT WORKS!!! - too early to completely celebrate but thank you! Might come back to this if it doesn't work everywhere

Answer (score 0):

You can just Replace `Count(*)` with `Count(Invoice_Number)`. Might be that works.

Comment: may i know what is apar_id here. If it makes no impact thewn remove this cond from sub-query in where condition.

Comment: Bulat suggested a solution that worked, have a look above.
 
apar_id is the identification number for the supplier i.e. Supplier ID